# Using logical operators in json path file

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, jsonpath

Is there a functionality to use logical operators in JSON path file used in copy command.

For example, I have a JSON which can contain a key which can either be

> Desc

Or

> Description

So in the JSON it would be something like -

```
{
"Desc": "Hello",
"City" : "City1",
"Age": "21"
}

{
"Description" : "World",
"City" : "City2",
"Age": "25"
}
```

I'm using copy command to pull the data from the JSON above into my table in redshift. The table has a column named "description_data". This would store values of either "Desc" or "Description". So I want my path file to identify using an "OR" condition.

This is the path file that I'm currently using -

```
{
"jsonpaths": [
               "$['Desc']",
               "$['City']",
               "$['Age']"
             ]
}
```

Which is working fine.

What I'm trying to do is the below (this is where I'm unsure if there is any syntax or functionality to achieve the objective)

```
   {
    "jsonpaths": [
                   "$['Desc']" or "$['Description']",
                   "$['City']",
                   "$['Age']"
                 ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Redshift doesn't support this.

You can issue two `copy` commands, one with `Desc`, and another with `Description`, to load the data into two temporary tables. After that, you can merge the two into your final table.